# Inner join returns correct MAX date but not other fields in same row

Tags: mysql, sql, join, max

I have the following db tables (simplified)

```
statistics_meter

id | mpan_number
1  | 12345678
2  | 87654321

statistics_contract
id  | contract_end_date  | meter_id  | supplier
1   | 2014-01-10         | 1         | British gas
2   | 2013-12-01         | 1         | Southern Electric
3   | 2014-03-01         | 2         | EON
```

My query is intended to get the most recent contract end date for a given meter and return it along with the supplier. I have written the query and am returning the correct contract end date **but** the supplier is returning from the previous contract - therefore returning data from across two rows, not just one.

e.g. i get

```
2014-01-10|Southern Electric
```

.. incorrect.

My query:

```
SELECT
    statistics_meter.mpan_number AS mpanNumber,
    MAX(statistics_contract.contract_end_date) AS contractEndDate,
    statistics_contract.supplier AS supplierName
FROM statistics_contract
    INNER JOIN statistics_meter 
        ON statistics_meter.id=statistics_contract.meter_id
GROUP BY statistics_contract.meter_id
```

thanks in advance for help

Comment: That is what happens when you don't understand how the database works.  Read about MySQL `group by` extensions in the documentation (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html).  The values for the columns not in `group by` are arbitrary.

Comment: Use a JOIN with a subquery filter.

Comment: I appreciate the link @GordonLinoff, but wouldn't you agree that if everybody knew the documentation inside out there would be no need for stackoverflow?

Comment: @newvision . . . The extended columns feature of MySQL is non-standard SQL.  If people are using something that is so far from the standard, then yes, I do think they should know what they are doing.  I have no idea why the construct is even taught.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this SQL query

```
SELECT
    statistics_meter.mpan_number AS mpanNumber,
    s.contract_end_date AS contractEndDate,
    s.supplier AS supplierName
FROM statistics_contract AS s
    INNER JOIN statistics_meter 
        ON statistics_meter.id=s.meter_id
WHERE s.contract_end_date = (
    SELECT MAX(contract_end_date) 
    FROM statistics_contract AS sc 
    WHERE sc.meter_id=s.meter_id
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It can't return other fields in the same row, because there is no ***same row***.  The concept of an aggregate is to generate a single value from the values in an ***arbitrary*** number of rows.  If there are 1200 rows in your table that satisfy the other criteria expressed in the query, then for any of the "other" fields, which of the possibly 1200 other different values would you want the query to return ??

to get the other data from one of the rows, you have to specify exactly which specific row you want.

```
SELECT m.mpan_number mpanNumber,
     c.contract_end_date, c.supplier supplierName
FROM statistics_contract c
   JOIN statistics_meter m 
    ON m.id=c.meter_id
where contract_end_date = 
      (Select Max(contract_end_date)
       From statistics_contract
       Where meter_id = c.meter_id)
```

... and even this may not work if there is more than one row in `statistics_contract` with the same `meter_id` and that last `contract_end_date`.